# Moshi R8/Relese issue

Tags: android, proguard, moshi

Moshi Version : 1.13.0
Kotlin Version : 1.7.0

Moshi pro file

```
# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}

### Moshi
-dontwarn com.squareup.moshi.**
-keep class com.squareup.moshi.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.moshi.** { *; }

-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

# The name of @JsonClass types is used to look up the generated adapter.
-keepnames @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class *

-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault

-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }


-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson <methods>;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson <methods>;
}

#### OkHttp, Retrofit and Moshi
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson <methods>;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson <methods>;
}

# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}

-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

# Enum field names are used by the integrated EnumJsonAdapter.
# Annotate enums with @JsonClass(generateAdapter = false) to use them with Moshi.
-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
}

# The name of @JsonClass types is used to look up the generated adapter.
-keepnames @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class *

# Retain generated JsonAdapters if annotated type is retained.
-keep class **JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
```

My release configuration

```
  isMinifyEnabled = true
      isDebuggable = true
      signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName(BuildTypes.RELEASE)

      val proguards = fileTree("proguard") {
        include("*.pro")
      }
      
      proguards.toList().forEach {
        println(it.nameWithoutExtension)
      }
      
      proguardFiles(
        getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
        "proguard-rules.pro",
        *proguards.toList().toTypedArray()
      )
```

I have been trying to resolve a moshi issue [image] .
It does not happen when i run the debug variant.

And I have absolutely no clue how to unravel this mystery .

Comment: Hello, Probably this solution can solve you problem => https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206855609#comment9